# Moving Object to certain location

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a method here that will either add or subtract the location to get to the set location that a person needs to get to if the box needs to move to the left it works great but if it needs to move to the right it doesn't seem to work I know there is a problem with it I just can't figure it out

```
    public void doMovements(float delta) {
    if (!movements.isEmpty()) {
        Vector2 vec = movements.get(0);

        if (pos.x > vec.x)
        pos.x -= VELOCITY * delta;
        else if (pos.x < vec.x)
        pos.x += VELOCITY * delta;

        System.out.println(pos.x);

        if (pos.x - vec.x < CLOSE_VEC) {
        movements.remove(movements.get(0));
        System.out.println(movements.size());
        }
    }

    rect.y = pos.y;
    rect.x = pos.x;
}
```

I need to get from point a to point b if the box has to move left it works perfectly but if it has to move right it breaks thanks for helping!

Comment: I figured out the problem, the problem is in the
`if (pos.x - vec.x < CLOSE_VEC)` if it has to move right the number is negative and it is returning that it has gotten close enough to stop moving. I don't know what equation I would use to find it if it's close enough to stop moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem I was checking if it was at the correct lane incorrectly
I needed to change

```
if (pos.x - vec.x < CLOSE_VEC) {
```

To

```
if (!(pos.x - vec.x < 0) && pos.x - vec.x < CLOSE_VEC) {
```

I need to make sure that the value isn't negative so the rectangle can move right.

Answer (score 0):

If you calculated `delta` by the difference of two values, it is probably negative sometimes.  They way you have it written, the code assumes that delta is always positive.  Have you made sure that the delta is an absolute value.

If delta is positive and negative, then you don't need two separate statements.  You do with just one:

```
pos.x += VELOCITY * delta;
```

Just make sure that delta is negative when it should be, and positive when it should be

Comment: delta is never negative as it's the time between each frame in seconds so it could never equal a negative number but I figured out the problem, the problem was 'if (pos.x - vec.x < CLOSE_VEC)' need to be changed to 'if (!(pos.x - vec.x < 0) && pos.x - vec.x < CLOSE_VEC)'